# Accepted answer doesn’t answer question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

[How can a man grow his chest early without gym?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/39191/how-can-a-man-grow-his-chest-early-without-gym)

So having sat down and written out an answer for this question I feel somewhat invested in it. That being said, the accepted answer clearly doesn’t answer the question being asked. I’m sure this isn’t the only case of this happening, but is there anything we can do?

The purpose of these websites is to provide answers to questions that people have or might have. Admittedly I’m a bit biased here, but I thought I’d ask.

Answer (score 4):

Simply downvote, provide a correct answer if you can, and move on. We cannot undo an accepted answer, that can only be done by the asker of the question.

If it is not accepted, you can flag it as not an answer, and depending on the actual quality of the answer, it may or may not be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

(Un)fortunately, moderators cannot award the "Accepted" checkmark, because only the asker can gauge whether or not their answer has been answered in a way that satisfies them. That's really one of the main factors that separates the Q&A format of SE from, say, a Wiki type site.

Future readers will likely take upvotes/downvotes into consideration when perusing answers because it's pretty well placed, and a lot of people are aware of how that works.

One course of action that I'd like to see is one where you, in your answer, refer to the accepted answer, and specifically debunk his/her postulates.